# Show that if $\dim X \ge 2$, then the wedge product with $\omega$ is injective on $1$-forms.

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

> Let $X$ be a connected complex manifold, and $h$ be a Kähler metric. Let $\omega$ be the associated Kähler form. Show that if $\dim X \ge 2$, then the wedge product with $\omega$ is injective on $1$-forms.

The given conditions are the following: $d\omega =0$ and locally $\omega = \frac{i}{2} \sum_{i,j}\omega_{i,j}dz_i \wedge d\bar{z}_j$. So we will suppose that $$\omega \wedge \eta = 0$$ and want to prove that $\eta = 0$ when $\eta \in \Omega^{1}(X)$. Locally we can write $\eta = \sum_k (f_kdz_k + g_kd\bar{z}_k)$ so $$\frac{i}{2} \sum_{i,j}\omega_{i,j}dz_i \wedge d\bar{z}_j \wedge \sum_k (f_kdz_k + g_kd\bar{z}_k)=0.$$ I'm kinda stuck here, this is not the most pleasant expressions to work with. Can we do something to simplify this or would it be better to forget about working locally here?

Comment: This is from Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry I, Voisin exercise $1$ on chapter $3$. There is no compactness condition mentioned there. @TedShifrin

Comment: I tried to see if there is an errata online for the book, but couldn't find any so I guess this is just not true. @TedShifrin

Comment: This fact does not require compactness and holds for all smooth forms. Since $\omega\wedge\cdot$ is $\mathbb{C}^\infty$ linear, it comes from a map $T^*X\to \bigwedge^3 T^* X$ and is injective if and only if the induced maps $T^*_xX\to \bigwedge^3 T^*X$ are injective. This is really an exercise in symplectic linear algebra, no complex geometry is needed. Cf: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799533/proving-the-wedge-product-of-a-nondegenerate-2-form-with-1-forms-is-injectiv

Comment: What is the issue with the counterexample that Ted provided? @J.V.Gaiter

Comment: In that case the $k,k,l$ component of $\omega\wedge\eta$ will vanish, but if $k\neq i$ and $\omega_{i,l}\neq 0$ then the $k,i,l$ component of $\omega\wedge\eta$ is non-zero.

Comment: I see. I'll try to use the same argument as in the link you provided. I think I need to use the basis for $(p,q)$-forms in this case? @J.V.Gaiter

Comment: In this case, much of the extra structure is not needed. Since any Kaehler manifold is symplectic with symplectic form given by $\omega$, it suffices to prove that for any symplectic manifold $\omega\wedge\cdot$ is injective on $1$-forms.

Comment: So if $\omega = \sum \omega_{j,k} dz_j \wedge d\bar{z}_k$ and $\eta = \sum_{l,m} a_l dz_l + b_md\bar{z}_m$ one has $$\omega \wedge \eta = 0 \implies \sum \omega_{j,k} dz_j \wedge d\bar{z}_k \wedge \left( \sum_{l,m} a_l dz_l + b_md\bar{z}_m\right) = 0.$$

If I got the calculations correctly this should result to $$\sum a_l\omega_{j,k}dz_j \wedge d\bar{z}_k \wedge dz_l + \sum b_m\omega_{j,k}dz_j \wedge d\bar{z}_k \wedge d\bar{z}_m = 0.$$ The first part  of the sum has now a $(2,1)$-form and the second a $(1,2)$-form.

Comment: The answer you provided to the linked question now considers the base $\{dz_j \wedge d\bar{z}_k \wedge dz_l,dz_j \wedge d\bar{z}_k \wedge d\bar{z}_m\}$ and arguing that since it's linearly independent the coefficients are $0$? @J.V.Gaiter

Comment: @TedShifrin No worries, happens to the best of us.

Comment: Not quite! In my comment on the other question, we use the fact that $T_x^*X$ admits a symplectic basis $e^i,f^i$ for which $\omega_p$ takes the standard form $\sum_{i=1}^n e^i\wedge f^i$. In general coordinates there could be some mixing of components which makes the use of this coordinate based argument somewhat intractible. It is a slightly non-trivial fact that there exist coordinates for which the Kahler form takes this form at $x$. This cannot, in general be done even locally (i.e. on an open neighborhood of $x$) as that would imply that $X$ is flat.